# How to create HTML file with Pie and Bar charts from WPF application

Tags: css, .net, wpf, html

Here is our scenario.

1. We have a dataset / DTOs which need to be displayed in a HTML file using HTML5 and CSS4
2. User will click on a Button from a (C#) WPF application on Windows 10 computer
3. On click, A HTML file should be saved which should display the data in Barcharts and Piecharts

Can anyone help here please ?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of fusion library. It will the work.